# How do you stack any block or item to over their limit?

Tags: terraria-console

How do you stack any block or item to over their limit in Terraria?

Comment: What makes you think this is possible?

Comment: I have been shown a stack with over 1000 on a shared game and when I researched this on you tube it seemed to say it was possible as somebody had items with higher limits than inventory levels would allow.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I believe it might be possible is through [map editing](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Map_viewers) or [inventory editing](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Inventory_editors), i.e. using external tools to mess with the game data. Note, however, this is unsupported and may crash the game, as well as corrupting your save. It can also be considered cheating.